# How do I get just one 301 redirect from http://www.olddomain.co.uk >> https://newdomain.uk?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to keep a redirect to a single hop

```
I want http://www.olddomain.co.uk >> https://newdomain.uk
```

But at the moment with the htaccess code below, it's going:

```
http://www.olddomain.co.uk >> https://www.olddomain.co.uk >> https://newdomain.uk
```

Is there a way I can get this down to just the one hop? i.e. if the domain is not https://newdomain.uk eg www. or http:// or another domain, 301 redirect straight to https://newdomain.uk with just one hop.

This is the htaccess code I've tried so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.co.uk$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.co.uk$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `http://www.olddomain.co.uk >> https://www.olddomain.co.uk` is not happening in your shown rule. Can you check if there is some rule in code or Apache config

Comment: Can PHP code execute before the above htaccess code?

Comment: PHP code is afterwards but Apache config will be before

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it and report back.